# Is backpropagation a frequentist approach?

Tags: bayesian, neural-networks

Frequentist statistics says that `there exists some true underlying parameters for a model`. While Bayesian statistics says that `there are different beliefs about parameters for a model`.

In backpropgation, we essentially throw data at a neural network, backpropagate the gradients error, and hope that the network learns the true underlying parameters.

Is training a neural network model with backpropagation, a frequentist approach?

Comment: I disagree that Bayesian statistics does not consider there is a true value for the parameter.

Comment: I was taught that there are various "beliefs" for the parameter. These beliefs are not right or wrong.

Comment: There is no "true" prior, but this does not mean there is no true parameter value behind the observed data.

Answer (score 4):

[Backpropagation](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Backpropagation_Algorithm) uses a regularizer $\lambda$ to penalize magnitudes of the weights to prevent overfitting. This is a frequentist approach to applying the [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) principle.

In the Bayesian formulation, this is expressed equivalently as putting a prior distribution on the weights. Your regularizer term $\lambda$ would now be expressed in terms of the prior hyperparameters.

Both approaches work and equivalent in an algorithmic sense. The Bayesian formulation might require a few additional math steps to see how $\lambda$ depends on the prior.

The frequentist approach would use cross-validation to determine $\lambda$ directly. Bayesian's may use cross-validation to fix a prior. Or they may not.